# How can I reset the Play Store content filter pin?

Tags: google-play-store, security, content-filter

I have forgotten my Google Play Content filter pin and would like to reset it so I can download some apps that are being blocked.

Does anyone know how I can reset the pin?

Comment: [This article](http://www.talkandroid.com/98577-google-play-pin-code-can-be-easily-disabled/) suggests that it can be disabled by clearing the app data for the Play Store. I'm not sure if that's still relevant though. EDIT: Confirmed it works on Android 4.4.

Answer (score 5):

You can reset the Content Filter pin by clearing the app data for the Play Store. This will clear the pin and also remove the filter.

1. Go to Settings > Apps
2. Tap on "Google Play Store"
3. Tap the "Clear Data" button.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to Settings > Apps
2. Tap on "Google Play Store"
3. Tap the "Clear Data" button.